# Xcuitest : Unable to enter complete text in textfield

Tags: swift, xcuitest

I have written code

```
XCUIElement.type("https://www.forture.com/store")
```

and taps on continue button

But when I am running my code, it sometimes enters only half string i.e. `https://www.forture.com/sto` OR `https://www.forture.com/s`

This is not always the case but only a few times.

is there any other way to enter complete lengthy string/text?

Comment: Are you by any chance running this on simulator?

Comment: I assume you mean `XCUIElement.typeText`? Have a look [over on the Apple Forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/5910) and read down a bit, ignoring that the original question is about secure input fields. In short: you should be ok if you turn the hardware keyboard off. Cmd+Shift+K does that or use the `IO/Keyboard` menu.